# Querying DataColumnCollection with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, asqueryable, datacolumncollection

I'm trying to perform a simple LINQ query on the Columns property of a DataTable:

```
from c in myDataTable.Columns.AsQueryable()
    select c.ColumnName
```

However, what I get is this:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. 'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'c'.

How can I get the DataColumnCollection to play nice with LINQ?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

How about:

```
var x = from c in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
        select c.ColumnName;
```

Comment: @Dave: What causes this issue in the first place? How come we have to do the Cast() ?

Comment: It's because dt.Columns is an IEnumerable, but not an IEnumerable<DataColumn>.  It's just a function of the fact that the class is a bit older and doesn't implement the new generic type.  When you Cast<>(), you cast to an IEnumerable<T> where the extension methods are defined.

Answer (score 19):

With Linq Method Syntax:

```
var x = myDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName);
```

Answer (score 16):

You could also use:

```
var x = from DataColumn c in myDataTable.Columns
        select c.ColumnName
```

It will effectively do the same as Dave's code: "in a query expression, an explicitly typed iteration variable translates to an invocation of Cast(IEnumerable)", according to the [`Enumerable.Cast<TResult> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) MSDN article.